# Goedel's first incompleteness theorem, the omega rule, and Tennant's reflection rule

Tags: logic, incompleteness, peano-axioms

Typical discussions of Goedel's first incompleteness theorem note that PA can prove of each integer that it doesn't number the proof of the Goedel sentence $G$. They then note that using an omega rule to infer from the infinite conjunction of all of them would get you $G$ but this fails to yield a finitary proof. [Neil Tennant has suggested](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/a/4597/files/2014/07/tennant_mind2002-1vn58c0.pdf) that a reflection rule or axiom for primitive recursive functions/relations, such as the proof predicate, would legitimately get us to $G$. Apparently, he believes that PA can prove

> for all integers $x$, $x$ is not the number of a proof of $G$

and then uses a reflection rule such as

> if no integer numbers the proof of $G$, then $G$

to get (via *modus ponens*) $G$.

I find this appealing. What I don't get is how Tennant/one gets to the universal generalization about all integers.  Is this simply good old mathematical induction? Obviously you get the base case. But how does one get from it holds for arbitrary integer $n$ to holding for $n+1$? Tennant must know he's doing but I sure don't. Someone explain or point me to a gentle explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a citation? I'm not familiar with Tennant's position here, and looking at [his publications list](http://u.osu.edu/tennant.9/publications/) I don't immediately see the relevant article.

Comment: Thanks. ‘Deflationism and the Gödel-Phenomena: Reply to Ketland’ [pdf], Mind vol. 114, no. 413, January 2005, pp. 89-96. You can download it on his Ohio State web page. It generated a number of replies etc. including Ketland & Shapiro among others. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, that was actually a follow-up paper, sorry, at work and let myself get distracted. His Ohio State page gives link to the original paper (Deflationism and the Godel-Phenomena" at https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/a/4597/files/2014/07/tennant_mind2002-1vn58c0.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I've taken the liberty of adding the link into the question directly.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't "good old mathematical induction" that is supposed to get the arithmetical reasoner to accept a $\Pi_1$ reflection principle, so much as philosophical reflection(!) on the practice he is immersed in.

I have a shot at explaining what this is supposed to mean in §36.5 of (the second edition of) my *Introduction to Gödel's Theorems*. [Here is a PDF of the relevant three pages](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/godelbook/Godel36.5.pdf). My discussion doesn't directly quote from Neil Tennant (or from Jeff Ketland, whose view appears in the para "You might protest..."). I didn't want to get into distracting exposition. But my discussion was intended to give the flavour of something close to Tennant's position, and as I recall he agreed with it.

(By the way, PA$\Pi$ is PA plus the $\Pi_1$ reflection principle which is easily shown to prove Con(PA) and hence the canonical Gödel sentence for PA.)

Comment: Is the $\Pi_1$ reflection principle $\square A \to A$ for when $A$ is $\Pi_1$ ?

Comment: Mr. Smith, Thank you. I have already learned much from my copy of the 2nd edition and Godel Without Tears. Having no gift for mathematics, these matters require a stretch for me and are sometimes beyond reach. Your excellent, clear writings have helped many of us. I for one am grateful.

Comment: Yes to DanielV, Thanks to Wayne W!

Comment: DanielV: No,it is not. Tennant’s earlier discussed (571-72) it but doesn't use it. His principle of “uniform primitive recursive reflection” is mid-p. 573: "(URp.r.) Add to S all sentences of the form ∀n (ProvS(ψ(n)) → ∀m ψ(m)  where ψ is prim recur."  Unlike □A→A his conditional sentence has distinct syntactic entities flanking the arrow. The variables in antecedent and consequent are (deliberately) distinct. This is important for Tennant, as he is trying to reconstruct Dummentt's semantic argument (Tennant p. 555)  in a syntact, deflationary-friendly manner.

Comment: Tennant tries to syntactically mirror Dummett's semantic argument, which moved from the infinite number of integer instances to a universal claim equivalent to G. Tennant wants a finitistic, deflationary syntactic proof. He  collapses the infinite number of integer instances into one sentence "for all n, where n is replaced by numerals, ~n Prov g" as antecedent, inserts an arrow after it, and as the consequent puts the G equivalent "for all m, where m is not limited to numerals, ~m Prov g." Two syntactically different sentences involved, needed in order to mirror Dummett. Finitary friendly??